# INST-07407: Unable to detect machine platform or JVM bits while installing oracle forms and reports

Tags: forms, oracle, report

I am installing oracle forms and reports in standalone system. After that I installed Oracle `Fusion middleware 12.1.3`. Then, I tried to install oracle forms and `reports 11.1.2.2.0` and hit the error. All are `64-bit` and even my laptop is `64-bit`. Presently I have installed `JDK 8u45` and `Middleware software`.

Java version:

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: you may check this link https://community.oracle.com/thread/2463633 or check installation guide.. http://www.arunainfo.net/docs/Oracle11gRel2Install.htm

Comment: this link is not of much help. I am still getting the error

Comment: Please check this http://holowczak.com/installing-oracle-forms-reports-11gr2/

Answer (score 0):

forms and reports 11.1.2.2.0 requires weblogic 10.3.6 (generic installer for 64bit)

Steps to install:

install java 1.7 jdk

in a command prompt:

- set JAVA_HOME=C:{where you installed Java JDK}
- set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
- install weblogic 10.3.6: java -jar wls1036_generic.jar

The only components you will need for forms and reports is Core Application Server, Administration Console, Configuration Wizard
The JDK selection should be pointing to your local JDK location
once this is complete you are ready to run the forms and reports installation.

After you finish the forms/reports install, then if you require the newer version of weblogic, install it into a new home.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Log-Files of the running Oracle installation, they are located in

`C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs`

respectively

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\logs`

For me I found out there that the installer was looking for `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe`

I then put the jdk there and then the installer was happy.